# jQuery allow specific numbers for mobile number

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to allow to enter mobile number with these combinations(7 or 8 or 9).

I just restricting the alphabets(allow only numbers) but how to restrict the numbers other than 7 or 8 or 9.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.mobnum', function (e) {
       //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
       if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
           if (e.which == 118){
             return true;
           }else{
             return false;
           }
      }
     });
```

Comment: You can use regex assuming for indian number i.e. like `^[789]\d{9}$`

Comment: thanks..but how to integrate while key press

Answer (score 2):

use following function to restict the mobile number

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.mobnum', function (e) {
    var mobnum="987654321";
    if (mobnum === ''|| mobnum === 'null'|| mobnum === null || phonenumber(mobnum)=== false) 
    {
    }
    else
    {
    your operations
    }
});
    function phonenumber(mobnum) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[789]\d{9}$/i);
    return pattern.test(mobnum);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use The `charAt()` method returns the character at the specified index in a string.

The index of the first character is 0, the second character is 1, and so on.

```
if (!(contactNumber.charAt(0) == "9" || contactNumber.charAt(0) == "8" || contactNumber.charAt(0) == "7")) {
            //DO THE VALIDATION
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to allow only digits:

```
// allow only numbers
var ctrlAltShift = false;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = true;
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode >= 16 && e.keyCode <= 18 ) ctrlAltShift = false;
});
$(document).on('keydown', '.mobnum', function(e) {
    if( 
        (
            !ctrlAltShift && (
                ( e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 ) || /* allow Digit 0 - 9 */
                ( e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) || /* allow Numpad 0 - 9 */
                ( $.inArray(e.keyCode, [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46]) !== -1 ) /* allow backspace, tab, esc, end, home, arrow left, arrow right, del */
            ) 
        ) ||
            ctrlAltShift && e.keyCode == 9 /* allow ctrl ( + shift ) + tab */
    ) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }        
});
```